# Customising Form Error Elements Symfony2

Tags: symfony

For my form - when an error occurs I want to have some generic "An error message has occurred" at the top of the form and any general form messages displayed (e.g. CSRF token invalid) - and then create the per form entity error messaging.

I had thought to call the

```
{{form_errors(form)}}
```

At the top of the page - then the

```
{{form_errors(form.element)}}
```

According to the docs it says it is possible

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

With the relevant section appearing to be

> You can also customize the error output for just one specific field type. For example, certain errors that are more global to your form (i.e. not specific to just one field) are rendered separately, usually at the top of your form:

> To customize only the markup used for these errors, follow the same directions as above, but now call the block form_errors (Twig) / the file form_errors.html.php (PHP). Now, when errors for the form type are rendered, your customized fragment will be used instead of the default form_errors.

However this seems to be the same instructions for how to template the element itself? I'm probably missing something here but how do I create one template for generic form errors and another for element specific errors?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to customize or do exactly ... the error template for a single form-row ... the error template for the errors on top of the form or which one? Can you please clarify that?

Comment: Both - I want a custom form block at the top of the form and one for each element